# Display the column name and add the row numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Dataframe that has this

```
 Id  | Tv title | action | Drama | Family | Sad | Other
---    -------   --------  -----  -------   ----  ------  
 1     TV Show1 |   0    |  1    |    1   |  0  |   0
 2     TV show2 |   0    |  0    |    0   |  0  |   0
 3     Tv Show3 |   0    |  1    |    1   |  0  |   0
```

I am trying to display the TV title and the sum where the genre is more than 1.

I have this, it adds up all the values (items been my df)

```
item.sum(axis=1)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Expected is something like this:

```
Tv Title  | # Genres |
--------    ---------
TV Show1  |   2
TV Show3  |   2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `Id` is your index and that it's irrelevant for the final answer. I think your almost there. Set `Tv title` as index:

```
n_genres = item.set_index('Tv title')
```

Do what you did:

```
n_genres = n_genres.sum(axis=1)
```

And filter for entries with non-zero genres

```
n_genres = n_genres.sum(axis=1)
n_genres[n_genres > 0]
```

Note that `n_genres` is a `pandas.Series` now.

*Alternatively* you can just sum over the columns that you want. Set-up code

```
item = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    data=[[1, 'TV Show 1', 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [2, 'TV Show 2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [3, 'TV Show 3', 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]],
    columns=['Id', 'Tv title', 'action', 'Drama', 'Family', 'Sad', 'Other']
)
item = item.set_index('Id')
```

Select only the columns you'd like to include in the sum

```
item['# Genres'] = item[['action', 'Drama', 'Family', 'Sad', 'Other']].sum(axis=1)
```

This gives a new column `'# Genres'` that can be used to selected lines where there's at least one genre:

```
item[['Tv title', '# Genres']].loc[item['# Genres'] > 0]
```

**Next time** please provide the set-up code. Makes live easier for people who wanna answer, but are not quite sure (like me :)